# Not able to run Petalinux in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

I am not able to launch Petalinux. The installation is done successfully. There is bash issue. How to fix it ?

```
INFO: Installing PetaLinux...
*********************************************
WARNING: You haven't specified the installation location.
*********************************************
*********************************************
WARNING: By default, it will be installed in your working directory: /scratch2/abc/Xilinx/Petalinux
*********************************************
Please input "y" to proceed the installation, "n" to exit otherwise:y
*********************************************
WARNING: PetaLinux installation directory: /scratch2/abc/Xilinx/Petalinux/. is not empty!
*********************************************
Please input "y" to continue to install PetaLinux in that directory?[n]y
INFO: Checking PetaLinux installer integrity...
INFO: Installing PetaLinux SDK to "/scratch2/abc/Xilinx/Petalinux/."
INFO: Installing buildtools in /scratch2/abc/Xilinx/Petalinux/./components/yocto/buildtools
INFO: Installing buildtools-extended in /scratch2/abc/Xilinx/Petalinux/./components/yocto/buildtools_extended
INFO: PetaLinux SDK has been installed to /scratch2/abc/Xilinx/Petalinux/.
abc@alpha:/scratch2/abc/Xilinx/Petalinux$ 

abc@alpha:/scratch2/abc/Xilinx/Petalinux$ /settings.sh
bash: /settings.sh: No such file or directory
```

The problem is same if I use dot

```
abc@alpha:/scratch2/abc/Xilinx/Petalinux$ ./settings.sh
bash: ./settings.sh: Permission denied
```

I also have tried with source. Still it complaint for bash.

```
abc@alpha:/scratch2/abc/Xilinx$ source Petalinux/settings.sh
PetaLinux environment set to '/scratch2/abc/Xilinx/Petalinux'
WARNING: /bin/sh is not bash! 
bash is PetaLinux recommended shell. Please set your default shell to bash.
WARNING: This is not a supported OS
INFO: Checking free disk space
INFO: Checking installed tools
INFO: Checking installed development libraries
INFO: Checking network and other services
WARNING: No tftp server found - please refer to "UG1144 2021.1 PetaLinux Tools Documentation Reference Guide" for its impact and solution
abc@alpha:/scratch2/abc/Xilinx$
```

When I run the "chsh -s /bin/bash" to change shell to bash. I get the following issue.

```
abc@alpha:/scratch2/abc/Xilinx$ chsh -s /bin/bash
Password: 
chsh: user 'abc' does not exist in /etc/passwd
abc@alpha:/scratch2/abc/Xilinx$
```

Comment: Again, you need to put the `.` in front of the `/` when you are running an executable command from a specific folder.  Use `./settings.sh` to run it.

Comment: You forgot the dot: **`./settings.sh`**

Comment: The problem is same if I use dot. I have edited the question.

Comment: You probably need to run `chsh` to change your shell then to bash so you can run it.  Have you completely read Petalinux installation and usage instructions before asking here?

Comment: Yes, I need to change shell to bash but I still have problem. I have edited the main question.

Comment: You need to give that user a password then.  Normally done by running `passwd abc`  You can also use `usermod` to set the login shell, etc for the user.

Comment: This use has sudo access and there is no other who is using the machine. I also run `passwd abc` but I get reply on terminal `passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
passwd: password unchanged`

Comment: Honestly, it sounds like your installation of Ubuntu is bad.  At this point I would recommend that you backup what you can then cleanly reinstall.  Those are simple commands that should have worked.

Answer (score 1):

you need make the file executeable. Run:

```
sudo chmod +x settings.sh
```

then try running it again:

```
./settings.sh
```

Alternatively you can run it without making it executebale by passing it to bash:

```
bash setting.sh
```